# Random CountDownTimer on 3 Activity

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I am a new user and have a question
how to auto roll activity with random countdown time ?

**example :** ActivityScreen1 display time in 50s-60s -> ActivityScreen2 display time in 30s-40s -> ActivityScreen2 display time in 50s-60s.

[image: Ex image]

Comment: What you have tried?

Comment: Please try something and post the problem you face while development. Sadly this isn't a code providing community. So you'll have to take some steps first you can go through https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: didn't understand your question ???

Answer (score 0):

Still I want you to learn Android first from some good tutorials. But I can guide you how you can achieve this.

- You will make a **[Service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services)**. Which will run in background.
- You will make a **[Handler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler)** in your service. That will call `postDelayed()` method.

Like this

```
final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        changeActivity(); // make this method & add your logic of checking current activity & setting new
    }
};

handler.postDelayed(r, 1000); // 1000 is millisecond, you will set time here.
```